# EF 4.0 : Include based on condition

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have the following Linq Expession being used in EF 4

```
var map = model.CDM_SubsidiaryDocumentMap.Where(m => m.SubsidiaryID == subsidiaryID)
                                         .Include("CDM_DocumentType")   
                                         .Include("CDM_DocumentType.CDM_DocumentHeader")                                                         
                     **(Need Help here)   Filter based on CDMDocumentType.CDM_DocumentHeader.ContactID == 123**
                                         .OrderBy(m => m.UISortOrder)
                                         .ToList();
```

How do I write the missing statement above, where in I include the nested child based on contactID filter.  Also note that CDM_DocumentType.CDM_DocumentHeader is a collection. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using the `from` syntax. Try something like this:

```
var map = (from m in model.CDM_SubsidiaryDocumentMap
           from dmh in m.CDM_DocumentType.CDM_DocumentHeader
           where m.SubsidiaryID == subsidiaryID
             && dmh.ContactID == 123
           order by m => m.UISortOrder
           select m).ToList();
```

If that doesn't work show more of your Entity Model, as I made and assumtion that CDM_DocumentType is a navigation property on CDM_SubsidiaryDocumentMap.

Comment: Thank You. It works. (the query above has a missing select m at the end)